# Prompting for a variable in when creating a release in TFS 2017 onpremise

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Folks,

I'd like to prompt the user to enter a value when manually creating a release.

At present, the user can select the build version to create the release from. I'd like the ability to enter additional information (well at least on string value).

Is this possible in TFS 2017 onpremise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not an option in TFS 2017. It is also not an option in TFS 2018 or in VSTS. You can submit a UserVoice item if you'd like Microsoft to implement that feature at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks.  I've worked around the issue by creating a variable and modifying the variable by editing the release definition.  It's ugly, but gets me past the limitation.  There is an existing user voice issue filed: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33227491-allow-setting-release-variables-at-queue-time Thanks for replying.